# Need to know how to decrypt this link: 0\u0082\u0003\u00bd0\u0082\u0002\u00a5\

Tags: android, encryption

I need to modify an APK.  The old version has a link of XML
but now after the update the link is encrypted and should be like this:

```
  # static fields
.field static final a:[Lcom/google/android/gms/common/k;


# direct methods
.method static constructor <clinit>()V
.locals 4

const/4 v0, 0x2

new-array v0, v0, [Lcom/google/android/gms/common/k;

const/4 v1, 0x0

new-instance v2, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ab;

const-string v3, "0\u0082\u0003\u00bd0\u0082\u0002\u00a5\u00a0\u0003\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0002\t\u0000\u00bf\u0081.I\u00c0\u001az\u000c0"

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/k;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)[B

move-result-object v3

invoke-direct {v2, v3}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ab;-><init>([B)V

aput-object v2, v0, v1

const/4 v1, 0x1

new-instance v2, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ac;

const-string v3, "0\u0082\u0003\u00bd0\u0082\u0002\u00a5\u00a0\u0003\u0002\u0001\u0002\u0002\t\u0000\u00e4\u00e4<\u00ec@\u008f~\u00e40"

invoke-static {v3}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/k;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)[B

move-result-object v3

invoke-direct {v2, v3}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ac;-><init>([B)V

aput-object v2, v0, v1

sput-object v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/aa;->a:[Lcom/google/android/gms/common/k;

return-void
.end method
```

I need to know how to decrypt this character to see the correct url link

Thanks!

Comment: Is com.google.android.gms.common in your APK? It's invoking some functions from classes from that package, which are likely to take part in the decryption. Also, I think you've messed up the code block, part of the code isn't in it, and some has been interpreted as a header. I tried to repair it with an edit, but spaces don't seem to count into the characters limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes com.google.android.gms.common is there! what can i give you more ?

Comment: The first thing which I think is missing is source of the function a(String) in class k in com.google.android.gms.common. Also, the constructor of com.google.android.gms.common.ab. And, this surely isn't java syntax. I use my common sense to interpret this code, but there are a few things I would like to check, so what is this language called? Some java bytecode assembly? What did you used to decompile it? Haven't you try to find something outputting java? Edit: Basically, to analyze this code you need everything it refers to.

Comment: Oh, and do you know where the URL in decoded form is used? This function returns void, so it is given as a parameter to some function. This would allow to narrow down the range of the code to analyze. It would also help if you would post the earlier version of this code. And you say you have the URL from earlier version. Isn't it working? I know this may seem stupid, but sometimes everyone misses things like that.